# How to write Anderson-Darling Test p-values loop?

Tags: r, sapply, p-value

I have this matrix called `matrix_1`:

```
    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
R1  27  38  94  40  4
R2  69  16  85  2   15
R3  30  35  64  95  6
R4  20  33  77  98  55
R5  20  44  60  33  89
R6  12  88  87  44  38
```

I would like to run an Anderson-Darling test (ad.test()) in a loop to compare the distribution of each column with a vector `vector_a`. I want the function to just return the p-value from `version 1`. Here is an example output using just one column compare to `vector_a`:

```
T.AD = ( Anderson-Darling  Criterion - mean)/sigma

Null Hypothesis: All samples come from a common population.

             AD  T.AD  asympt. P-value
version 1: 12.9 15.72        2.416e-07
version 2: 12.9 15.76        2.371e-07
```

I am trying this:

```
sapply(1:ncol(matrix_1), function(i) ad.test(as.vector(matrix_1[,1:i]), vector_a)$p)
```

but it overloads the cpu and I am not getting a result.

Comment: Please also show the command that generated the output. Also, review its structure, `str`, to see how to retrieve p-values.

Comment: How about: `sapply(matrix_1, function(col) ad.test(col, vector_a)$p)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good form to identify the package you are using

```
library(kSamples)
```

The test results are in $ad. Version 1 is the first row. P-value is third column, so you can capture this with

```
'output'$ad[1,3]
```

Using a sample vector, and setting up your matrix data

```
vector_a <- sample(0:100, 6)
rownames <- paste0("R", seq(1,6))
colnames <- paste0("C", seq(1,5))
matrix_1 <- matrix(
c(27,  38,  94,  40,  4,
69,  16,  85,  2,   15,
30,  35,  64,  95,  6,
20,  33,  77,  98,  55,
20,  44,  60,  33,  89,
12,  88,  87,  44,  38),
nrow = 6, ncol = 5, , dimnames = list(rownames, colnames))
```

You can use the apply function, specifying '2' to iterate over columns

```
apply(matrix_1, 2, function(matrix_column) ad.test(as.vector(matrix_column), vector_a)$ad[1,3])
```

Gives the version 1 p-value for each column

```
     C1      C2      C3      C4      C5 
0.12623 0.02507 0.39935 0.81181 0.28477
```

EDIT to address comment about the one step function
`matrix_column` is the function's argument name. It can be any name you wish.  Here is answer broken into parts:

```
# Define function
ad_function <- function(matrix_column){
  ad_test_results <- ad.test(as.vector(matrix_column), vector_a) # ad.test comparing matrix_column (columns of matrix) and vector_a. Assign results to ad_test_results
  ad_test_results$ad[1,3] # This gets the p-value for version 1
}
```

```
# Now apply the matrix columns to the function
apply(matrix_1, 2, ad_function)
```

Comment: why are you using ```matrix_column```? How does ```function()``` recognize that you are referring to the columns of the matrix?

Comment: ```matrix_column``` is function's argument name. I called it that to be clear that we will be applying the function to the matrix's columns. The apply function applies the rows (specifying '1' as second argument) or columns ('2' as second argument). I used 2 so it feeds across columns. See edited answer where I broke apart the one line answer into the function and then applied the function. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks this helps